# Intermittent Active Directory login issues on Lion

Tags: login, active-directory

We bought a 27" iMac for our CEO. And we brought in some consultants to hook it up to our windows Active Directory using ADmitMac. Back when we were on 10.6.x things were hunky dory. But then our CEO upgraded to 10.7 and the fun started.

The fun I'm referring to is a horribly maddening and difficult to reproduce issue where sometimes when the mac comes out of sleep mode it refuses to accept his active directory credentials until we reboot the system. Typically this happens at a critical juncture resulting in a very angry CEO. Angry CEOs are not good for stable employment.

Any idea how to isolate and fix this issue, short of just rebuilding the iMac and praying?

UPDATE: apparently clicking switch users also allows him to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we ran down the culpert -- said CEO upgraded himself to Lion without our knowledge and consent. And turned on the wifi to an AP that can't resolve our domain controllers. Sometimes, when logging back in, he reached out on the wrong connection and it got a bit confused.